# Choose between Onedrive W10 sync over Onedrive for business sync

Tags: onedrive, office365

My company has an Office 365 subscription.

We have several team site with document library I want to sync locally.

Onedrive for business synchronization client is know to be very unreliable, compared to native Windows 10 Onedrive client.

However, Onedrive for business is installed with my Office 365 setup and is automatically used for sync.

How can I force the W10 onedrive sync to handle file sync?

I tried to uninstall Onedrive for business, but without success.

I even setup a custom config file for installation, but the client sync app is still present.

```
<Configuration>
  <Add SourcePath="http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60/" OfficeClientEdition="64" >
    <Product ID="O365BusinessRetail">
      <Language ID="fr-fr" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" />
</Configuration>
```

Still not able to not uninstall this software.

Comment: "How can I force the W10 onedrive sync to handle file sync?" - You can't.  OneDrive for Business Syncs in an entirely different way and desination then OneDrive.  OneDrive cannot Sync to the location OneDrive for Business Syncs to.

Comment: OneDrive is also a feature of Windows 10.  OneDrive for Business is on purpose a seperate application.  "till not able to not install this software." - Don't you mean uninstall the application?

Comment: Windows 10's onedrive client **is** able to sync SharePoint : https://blogs.office.com/2015/09/30/meet-the-new-onedrive-for-business/

Comment: Or at least, it's unclear

Comment: I see evidence that OneDrive for Business can connect to your OneDrive account but I don't see any evidence that OneDrive can connect to your Sharepoint account( i.e. the account ONeDrive for Business uses).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OneDrive Clients are being merged.  What you want is the new OneDrive Sync client that can sync Business, personal, and SharePoint libraries.  Currently the last part of that (SharePoint sync) is in the preview phase - but it's been working fairly well for us with no issues.

Just to clarify the features in preview are currently the SharePoint library pieces, the OneDrive syncing functions have ben GA for a little while now. You can check it out here:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-syncing-SharePoint-sites-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-Preview-6de9ede8-5b6e-4503-80b2-6190f3354a88

Your end goal here should be to get off the groove client based sync tool.  It's the one that carries the bad reputation.  The current one works much better.